# Confirm с альтернативными ответами в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, es5

Возможно ли сделать `confirm` где кнопки будут содержать не 'ОК' и 'Отмена', а другие значения, к примеру 'Да' и 'Нет'?

Comment: Нет. Только писать свой (или найти) на js

Comment: И наверное вы имели в виду confirm. У alert одна кнопка

Comment: Да, имел в виду confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На ванильном Javascript нельзя, но вы можете воспользоваться jquery для создания собственных окон подтверждения https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: "На ванильном Javascript нельзя" - а что есть jQ?)